# Non-exhaustive patterns in Haskell function

Tags: haskell

Dear All:  I have a problem with the following simple function:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print (fac ["aa", "bb", "cc"])

fac ::[String] -> String
fac []= ""
fac (x:[])= x
fac (x:[xs]) = x++ (fac [xs])
```

The function works OK for two elements in a list:

```
*Main> fac ["aa","bb"]
"aabb"
it :: [Char]
(0.02 secs, 0 bytes)
```

however it fails when there are three elements:

```
*Main> fac ["aa","bb","cc"]
"*** Exception: main1.hs:(4,1)-(6,29): Non-exhaustive patterns in function fac
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: FYI the pattern `(x:[])` can also be written as `[x]`.

Comment: I understand that your are trying to learn but just as a note: there are functions that will solve this for you - for example [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) - you can find those easily using [**Hoogle**](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [**Hayoo**](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) plus you can directly look at their implementation (the *source* link on hackage - although it might not help you much here as it's implemented using a *fold*)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

```
fac (x:[xs]) = x++ (fac [xs])
```

you should use

```
fac (x:xs) = x ++ (fac xs)
```

`[xs]` matches a list with a single element, while `xs` can match an entire list of any length, which is what you wanted.

PS: `fac (x:[])= x` is redundant. Without it, `x:[]` would be `x ++ fac []` = `x ++ ""` = `x` anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @thatotherguy's answer, you could reduce your code to:

```
fac ::[[Char]] ->[Char]
fac [] = ""
fac (x:xs) = x ++ (fac xs)
```

Since you are already handling the case where input is `[]`, the pattern `(x:xs)` will cover the case `xs = []`, so you only need 2 patterns to be matched.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/FPDT64798)

Comment: +1 for the **Demo** ... but maybe you should get a more interesting sample there ;) (the OP gave `fac ["aa", "bb", "cc"]` for example)